# hadoop taskdetails jsp page is not accessible

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Within Hive CLI while trying to create an index on a table I run in to the error

Error: Java heap space

right above this line is a URL

http://hadoop-e1e-m-01:8088/taskdetails.jsp?jobid=job_1447411380955_0006&tipid=task_1447411380955_0006_m_000000

However that URL is not accessible. When I visit that URL I find the following contents

```
HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /taskdetails.jsp. Reason:

NOT_FOUND
```

I have enabled job history by issuing `mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh start historyserver`

**Question** What daemon or service should I start so that I have access to that page?

Here is the log from the session:

```
alter index vzt_oct_01_lon_idx on vztraction_oct_01 rebuild
Query ID = hadoopuser_20151113144833_fa89f224-7a81-43ea-b5dd-97bacc655976
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks not specified. Estimated from input data size: 2
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
Starting Job = job_1447411380955_0007, Tracking URL = http://hadoop-e1e-m-01:8088/proxy/application_1447411380955_0007/
Kill Command = /home/hadoopuser/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1447411380955_0007
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 2; number of reducers: 2
2015-11-13 14:48:40,784 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2015-11-13 14:48:50,018 Stage-1 map = 50%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 10.81 sec
2015-11-13 14:48:58,244 Stage-1 map = 67%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 62.23 sec
2015-11-13 14:49:00,299 Stage-1 map = 67%,  reduce = 8%, Cumulative CPU 62.5 sec
2015-11-13 14:49:01,328 Stage-1 map = 67%,  reduce = 17%, Cumulative CPU 80.95 sec
2015-11-13 14:49:17,755 Stage-1 map = 50%,  reduce = 17%, Cumulative CPU 66.62 sec
2015-11-13 14:50:18,103 Stage-1 map = 50%,  reduce = 17%, Cumulative CPU 161.62 sec
2015-11-13 14:51:18,285 Stage-1 map = 50%,  reduce = 17%, Cumulative CPU 162.83 sec
2015-11-13 14:52:18,392 Stage-1 map = 50%,  reduce = 17%, Cumulative CPU 163.74 sec
2015-11-13 14:53:18,453 Stage-1 map = 50%,  reduce = 17%, Cumulative CPU 164.43 sec
2015-11-13 14:54:18,470 Stage-1 map = 50%,  reduce = 17%, Cumulative CPU 164.97 sec
2015-11-13 14:55:18,476 Stage-1 map = 50%,  reduce = 17%, Cumulative CPU 165.52 sec
2015-11-13 14:56:19,491 Stage-1 map = 50%,  reduce = 17%, Cumulative CPU 392.65 sec
2015-11-13 14:56:28,644 Stage-1 map = 67%,  reduce = 17%, Cumulative CPU 68.3 sec
2015-11-13 14:57:01,181 Stage-1 map = 50%,  reduce = 17%, Cumulative CPU 393.08 sec
2015-11-13 14:58:01,530 Stage-1 map = 50%,  reduce = 17%, Cumulative CPU 393.67 sec
2015-11-13 14:58:33,252 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 10.81 sec
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 10 seconds 810 msec
Ended Job = job_1447411380955_0007 with errors
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
Job Tracking URL: http://hadoop-e1e-m-01:8088/proxy/application_1447411380955_0007/
Examining task ID: task_1447411380955_0007_m_000001 (and more) from job job_1447411380955_0007

Task with the most failures(4): 
-----
Task ID:
  task_1447411380955_0007_m_000000

URL:
  http://hadoop-e1e-m-01:8088/taskdetails.jsp?jobid=job_1447411380955_0007&tipid=task_1447411380955_0007_m_000000
-----
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
Error: Java heap space

FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 2  Reduce: 2   Cumulative CPU: 10.81 sec   HDFS Read: 58031791 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 10 seconds 810 msec
```

Hadoop version 2.7.0
Hive version 1.2.1